# memcached resource requirements

Tags: php, memcached

I'm a newbie to memcache. My host(hostgator) says they recommend on memcahce on VPS 5 & up. I'm on VPS 4 (Centos, 2 Ghz, 1.3 GB ram 60 GB HDD) & VPS 5 is Centos, 2.7Ghz, 1.8GB ram, 80GB hdd.

Does memcache require so much resources ? I thought that VPS4 should do but my host thinks other wise. Can anyone suggest why memcahced resource needs are so high ?
thanks
Anita

Comment: It definitively depends on how you'll use memcache. Can you give more info about your usage of memcache?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how much data you want to store using memcache. All data will be kept in RAM, so if you are going to keep there a lot of data you will also need a lot of RAM. Well.. if your VPS4 RAM is completely used by sites/apps you already have there - it is reasonable to use VPS 5 (or even a system with large amount of RAM). Of course, it will use some additional CPU resources, but it needs should not be very high. But if you have on your VPS something simple enough - than it looks like they just want to sell VPS 5.

Comment: Hm, after thinking a while bout this... Seems like he must count "how much" data he loads and answer on this question himself.

Comment: Seems like i translate your question a bit wrong, so sry, now all is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Determine how much data you are going to need to cache?  You just need to have an idea for what size the data objects are going to be and how many of them you think there will be.

You really just need to look at the memcached stats... probably shoot for a hit rate of 90%+ (depending on application needs), an eviction rate of 0, and and perhaps around 50% memory usage when the cache is fully populated to provide for any growth needs, spikes, etc.

Once you know how much that memory allocation is, you can size your server's memory properly.